# why does the loop I make only produce one value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I want to display an array of jawaban but only produce one first value

```
public static function GetUserSoal($id)
{
    $model = Soal::where('cluster_id', $id)->inRandomOrder()->limit(500)->get();

    return view('components.User.showexam', compact('model'));
}
```

This is blade file :

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($model); $i++)            
    <form action="/jawaban/store/{{$model[$i]->id}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    @csrf
        <table id="datatable" style="width:100%">
        <tbody>           
            <tr>{{$i+1}}. </tr>
            <tr>{{$model[$i]->soal}}</tr>
            <ol type="A" style="">
                <li> {{$model[$i]->A}}</li>
                <li> {{$model[$i]->B}}</li>
                <li> {{$model[$i]->C}}</li>
                <li> {{$model[$i]->D}}</li>
                <li> {{$model[$i]->E}}</li>
            </ol>
        <input list="browsers" name="jawaban[{{$model[$i]->id}}]">
            <datalist id="browsers">
              <option value="A">
              <option value="B">
              <option value="C">
              <option value="D">
              <option value="E">
            </datalist>
        @endfor
            <br>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-right" id="modal-btn-save-jwb">Done</button>
    </form>
```

the controller :

```
public function GetUserJawaban($id, Request $request)
{   

    $score = 0;
    foreach($request->jawaban as $key => $value){
            return "Urutan ke-$key adalah $value";
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE0Nm.png)

when I add jawaban value like the picture above it only display 
"Urutan ke-29 adalah B", is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this function. Change return to echo. Return stops execution in first iteration and exits the function.

```
public function GetUserJawaban($id, Request $request)
{   

    $score = 0;
    foreach($request->jawaban as $key => $value){
            echo "Urutan ke-$key adalah $value";
    }

}
```

However, you may have to make a minor change where you use this function to avoid double echo problem.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you write return in a function, it will end all the processing and return a value.

So everything after the return will not be executed..